# Where are the files in Windows Azure

Tags: azure

Where do the files for a Windows Azure cloud service reside? I have been looking and looking and I can't seem to find it. I need to make some changes to some of the files and I can't find them. Is there like a cPanel File Manager available?

Comment: Enable remote desktop for the service, and you can remote in and do what you need.

Comment: Manually changing files in a cloud service (web or worker role) is a very bad idea. Next time Azure chooses to move your instance you will lose any manual changes and the default package in blob storage will be redeployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by a cloud service.

**PaaS** = You can only change files by creating a new CSPKG and deploying it.  You cannot modify files via RDP.
**IaaS** = RDP to the VM and do whatever you want to do.  You can also use things like WinRM, service extensions, Chef/Puppet, etc
**Websites** = Update the file in your repository (ie. Github) or upload the file via FTP

Answer (score 1):

Every instance in an Azure Cloud Service is a virtual machine. The files are deployed to each instance created during your deployment. Follow the instructions here: [Using Remote Desktop with Azure Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg443832.aspx).  Then from the Azure Panel select the slot (Production or Staging), select Instances, select the desired instance and at the bottom, click Connect.  This will download an RDP file. Open it and remote in to the instance.

The files in your deployment will be located on a virtual drive, typically E: for F:
 in F:\sitesroot\0

Comment: Be careful with this answer because it doesn't really help address the scenario posed in the question.  The scenario is to modify the files on the VM, which you can't do* via this RDP method for a PaaS service.  *Technically you can do this, but only for testing/dev purposes - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/09/05/how-to-modify-a-running-azure-service.aspx.

Comment: Concur with kwill! Files should be updated via deployment - any changes you make will not survive VIP swap (staging to production) deployemnts.

Comment: The "connect" button at the bottom of the page is inactive. What could be responsible for this?

Comment: You haven't setup remote access. Follow the instructions linked in the answer.